# Does KineticJS have library support for SVG?

Tags: html, canvas, svg, kineticjs, fabricjs

I've been looking at both [FabricJS](http://fabricjs.com) and [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com) as potential solutions for a project I'm working on, and like the library level support that FabricJS has for SVG. However its lack of zooming and panning functionality leaves me wanting more. For that reason, I began looking (again) at KineticJS.

I don't see much in KineticJS documentation regarding SVG support and I was wondering if someone could tell me whether KineticJS supports rendering SVG images or not as part of its framework. I assume that as far as KineticJS is concerned, SVG is just another Image and therefore should be treated as such in the framework.

Also, when I search for articles online regarding SVG and canvas, I see pages and articles discusing **SVG or Canvas**. I didn't think the two were mutually exclusive. Does the `<canvas>` element not natively support SVG?

Comment: We'll likely have support for zooming in Fabric in the next month or so

Comment: @kangax very cool, I will look for it then. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As you suspect, canvas and KineticJS both treat SVG as just another image.**

Yes, the canvas element can use its `drawImage` to draw an svg image.

And Yes, you can load SVG images into kineticJS also:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 400,
    height: 400
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var img=new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    var image = new Kinetic.Image({
        image: img,
        x: 20,
        y: 20,
        width: 75,
        height: 75,
    });
    layer.add(image);
    layer.draw();

}
img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/rocket.svg";
```

On the other hand,

FabricJS has more support for manipulating the SVG element.

Comment: `drawImage(<svg>)` is not fully cross-browser though. Last time I tested, Opera 12 didn't support it — http://kangax.github.io/jstests/canvas-drawimage-svg/ I suspect mobile browsers could have problems with it too.

Comment: Thanks for the details about the issues with cross-browser support. Going to mark this answer as accepted even with that caveat as I think it answers my original inquiry. :)

Answer (score 1):

KineticJS supports SVG via the path shape.  Here's a tutorial on that:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-path-tutorial/

Comment: The link is now broken.